Does std::unique_ptr support fancy pointers?

Can std::unique_ptr manage pointers only, or fancy pointers (pointer-like types) too?

I assume "fancy pointers too", because for resources like files/sockets, fancy pointers can be a great tool. And there seems no reason std::unique_ptr shouldn't support them.

Why are there inconsistent ways to test empty-ness of the managed pointer?

There are different ways to test empty-ness of the managed pointer in std::unique_ptr (GCC):

In ~unique_ptr(): if (__ptr != nullptr) (code)
In reset(): if (__old_p) (code)
In operator bool(): return get() == pointer() ? false : true; (code)

The problem is that they have different requirements to the pointer type:

bool operator ==(pointer, nullptr_t)
operator bool()
bool operator ==(pointer, pointer)

The inconsistent usage means all of them are needed, while one of them would suffice semantically.
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class File {
    FILE * pf_ = nullptr;
public:
    File() = default;
    File(const char * pathname) { /*...*/ };
    void Close() { /*...*/ };

    // All are needed to make std::unique_ptr work
    explicit operator bool() const { return pf_ == nullptr; }
    bool operator ==(nullptr_t) const { return pf_ == nullptr; }
    bool operator ==(File) const { /*...*/ return true; };
};

struct FileCloser {
    using pointer = File;
    void operator ()(File p) const { p.Close(); }
};

int main() {
    using FilePtr = unique_ptr<File, FileCloser>;
    FilePtr p(File("./abc"));
    if(p)
        p.reset();
}

https://godbolt.org/z/fjPjWzzhW
IMHO, std::unique_ptr should require minimum from the pointer type. One solution is to add a static member, e.g. __test_p, and use it to test empty-ness consistently:
template<typename T, typename D = std::default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr
{
// ...
private:
    static constexpr bool __test_p(pointer p) noexcept {
        if constexpr (is_convertible_v<pointer, bool>)
            return bool(p);
        else if constexpr (requires {{ p != nullptr} -> convertible_to<bool>; })
            return p != nullptr;
        else
            return p != pointer();
    }
// ...
};


You have made an example that compiles and runs. Can you clarify what kind of answer you are looking for the question "Does std::unique_ptr support fancy pointers?" Perhaps the post would be clearer if the actual question was at the end of the post and in the title.

You are overcomplicating things. You have File class which wraps FILE * type. So just use destructor of you File class to close file.

It supports a pointer-like type that implements NullablePointer. The pointer type is specified via the deleter's pointer member.

"IMHO, std::unique_ptr should require minimum from the pointer type" - Yeah, well, you know, that's just like, uh, your opinion, man. Unfortunately, the pointer member type must satisfy NullablePointer https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

To be honest I have no idea what "fancy pointers" are, they are not described anywhere in the C++ standard.  And std::unique_ptr is implicitly convertible to bool (to check for emptiness) so all in all what's your point? If you want more behavior write a custom wrapper around FILE (or just use std::iostream and get ALL the C++ benefits)

@MarekR If you did that, then File serves 2 masters; first, it is an API wrapper around a FILE*, and it is an RAII manager.  Sometimes you are working with C code that provides a FILE* you do not own, or you need to provide a FILE* to C code that may take ownership; the File class as written makes both of those operations easier.  (Ie, you can safely do File(SOME_FILE_POINTER).Operation() without closing the file).  Then, the unique pointer to File adds RAII features.

Also, in your example this using FilePtr = unique_ptr<File, FileCloser>; will be ultra-confusing, because std::is_same_v<FilePtr::pointer, FilePtr::element_type> is true.

@pptaszni that's the whole point of fancy pointers. Why do you think std::unique_ptr defines pointer the way it does?

@Caleth well oki, I recognize the flexibility and possible usefulness of this design, but I still would say it's rather confusing.

Does std::unique_ptr support fancy pointers? Yes, as demonstrated by your fancy pointer File example.


Can std::unique_ptr manage pointers only, or fancy pointers (pointer-like types) too?

Yes
The requirements for std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> are:

Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an argument of type unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer.

std::remove_reference_t<Deleter>::pointer, if it exists, must satisfy NullablePointer.


Among other things, a NullablePointer must satisfy all three of the requirements you claim are inconsistent, and they must all be consistent with each other.

Why are there inconsistent ways to test empty-ness of the managed pointer?

Having "redundant" operations is a trade off in favour of users of a constraint against implementors of a constraint, it is not "wrong".
While it is true that operator bool must be equivalent to ptr != nullptr, and ptr == nullptr must be equivalent to ptr == pointer(nullptr), it's more ergonomic to have operator bool and all the comparisons. By ensuring that every NullablePointer can do every operation that raw pointers can, code can be written expecting raw pointers, and "just work" for fancy pointers.

IMHO, std::unique_ptr should require minimum from the pointer type.

That's your opinion. The committee chose otherwise.

Thanks for the explanations! I guess it would've been less confusing if it's implemented via concept,  though I understand unique_ptr was introduced before concept.

@DoZerg the same tradeoff exists with concepts
